# launching a remote detached process with fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I wan to run a program remotely using fabric in python

If i run a program on machine A :

```
with (settings(host_string = machine_B_ip, user = 'ubuntu', key_filename = 'somepemfile.pem')):
    run('myprog')
```

It runs fine, but when machine A disconnects form machine B the process stops on B.
I solve this using 'nohup'

The real problem, though, is that machine A gets stuck, waiting on machine B

Trying:

```
run('myprog &')
```

Just doesnt work, the program does not run remotely (As is evident in http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.4/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang)

Trying:

```
run('myprog >& /dev/null < /dev/null &') # fails
run('myprog >& /dev/null < /dev/null') 
run('nohup myprog >& /dev/null < /dev/null')  # gets stuck
```

does not help.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

> run('nohup myprog >& /dev/null < /dev/null &')

?

With the `&` at the end?

Comment: I did, anything with & at the end fails in fabric

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer.

**Backgrounded processes may still prevent the calling shell from exiting until they stop running**

https://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.5/faq.html